# IHTMLDocument InvokeMember return javascript how to convert to C# object

Tags: c#

C#:

```
public object InvokeScript(string ScriptName, object[] Data){
    .....
    return oScript.GetType().InvokeMember(ScriptName,
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, oScript, Data);
}
```

javascript:

```
var myuser= [{a:3,b:4},{c:9,d:10}];
```

c# call:

```
object result = web.InvokeScript("myuser");
```

how can access result object ?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316.aspx), although I'm not completely sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I extend an  window browser object using

> web_browser.ObjectForScripting = new SharedObject();

Callback params return as array

> ```
> [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
> [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
> public class SharedObject
> {
>     public void GetValue(string name, object callback)
>     {
>         // === some code === ...
>         SendCallback(callback, result);
>     }
>
>     protected void SendCallback(object callback, object value)
>     {
>         callback.GetType().InvokeMember(
>             name: "[DispID=0]",
>             invokeAttr: BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
>             binder: null,
>             target: callback,
>             args: new Object[] { value });
>     }
>
> }
> ```